# relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cfree'

Tags: c, linux, cygwin, decision-tree

I am trying to compile `C4.5` algorithm in `Cygwin` for `Win64`. I have error as

```
besttree.o:besttree.c:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `cfree'
besttree.o:besttree.c:(.text+0x240): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cfree'
```

When I look at besttree.c, I found the cfree in

```
FormTarget(Size)
/*  -----------  */
    ItemNo Size;
{
    ItemNo i, *ClassFreq;
    ClassNo c, Smallest, ClassesLeft=0;

    ClassFreq = (ItemNo *) calloc(MaxClass+1, sizeof(ItemNo));



    while ( ClassesLeft )
    {
    /*  Find least common class of which there are some items  */

    Smallest = -1;
    ForEach(c, 0, MaxClass)
    {
        if ( ClassFreq[c] &&
         ( Smallest < 0 || ClassFreq[c] < ClassFreq[Smallest] ) )
        {
        Smallest = c;
        }
    }

    /*  Allocate the no. of items of this class to use in the window  */

    TargetClassFreq[Smallest] = Min(ClassFreq[Smallest], Round(Size/ClassesLeft));

    ClassFreq[Smallest] = 0;

    Size -= TargetClassFreq[Smallest];
    ClassesLeft--;
    }

    cfree(ClassFreq);
}
```

What could be the problem in this compile? Is it because of compiling in Cygwin for Win64? 
I can't locate the source of cfree api as well.
Thanks

Comment: According to this discussion, I have to use the pc with linux os to compile the C4.5. As glibc is a big package and Cygwin doesn't carry. cfree is in glibc.

Comment: the foreach() function is not part of C, so exactly what is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is C4.5 can't be compiled in Cygwin as Cygwin doesn't carry complete library as those in Linux. So I install Ubuntu as Virtual OS in my Windows machine. Then, I can compile successfully.